# Parsing and Writing on Huge XML files taking long time?

Tags: python, xml

I am Trying to parse a huge XML file > 1GB and replace some of the element's text values.
Its working but it takes a lot of times ( more than 15minutes ).

Is there any way to increase the perf of my scripts ?

My code for the parsing is something like that:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

 tree = ET.parse(path)
 root = tree.getroot()
for element in root.findall( My_Xpath_NS +'InstdAmt'):
    Somme_Indiv = element.text = Sample_Indiv
    Somme_Indiv = float(Somme_Indiv)
    Somme_Total += Somme_Indiv
    Counter_Transaction += 1


for element2 in root.findall(My_Xpath_NS+'CtrlSum') :
    Impot_Total = element2.text = str(Somme_Total)

    print(Impot_Total)

for element in root.findall(My_Xpath_NS + 'IBAN'):
    IbanFictif = "Fake"
    Iban_Fictif = element.text = str(IbanFictif)

for date_Today in root.findall(My_Xpath_NS + 'CreDtTm'):
    date_Today.text = str(today) + "T00:00:00"
for Date_User in root.findall(My_Xpath_NS + 'ReqdColltnDt'):
    Date_User.text = User_Date

for Transaction in root.findall(My_Xpath_NS + 'NbOfTxs'):
    Transaction.text = str(Counter_Transaction)


for Customer_Names in root.findall(My_Xpath_NS + 'Nm'):
    full_name = random.choice(first_name) + " " + random.choice(last_name)
    Customer_Names.text = full_name


tree.write(path , xml_declaration=True, method='xml', encoding='UTF-8')
```

I am sure the problem is that there is multiple for loops, maybe its not optimised and that's why it take so long no ?

the xml file looks like that ( but the real one is way bigger )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi = "sample" xmlns ="sample2">
   <CstmrDrctDbtInitn>     
        <GrpHdr>
            <MSgId>sample1</MSgId>
            <CreDtTm>2020-09-21T00:00:00</CreDtTm>
            <NbOfTxs>4</NbOfTxs>
            <CtrlSum>4</CtrlSum>
            <InitgPty>
                <Nm>sample</Nm>
                <Id>
                    <OrgId>
                        <Othr>
                            <IBAN>fake</IBAN>
                        </Othr>
                     </OrgId>
                </Id>
            </InitgPty>
        </GrpHdr>
        <InitgPty1>
            <InstdAmt>0.01</InstdAmt>
            <InstdAmt>0.01</InstdAmt>
            <InstdAmt>0.01</InstdAmt>
            <InstdAmt>0.01</InstdAmt>
        </InitgPty1>
    </CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
</Document>
```

Comment: You could try to structure a bit your algorithm. Right now you're abusing *findall*. But it's hard to figure things out without a sample file. Please share somehow one, in order for us to take a look at it. Are the *.xml* files structured in the same way? Also, please post some code that doesn't raise exceptions.

Comment: I edit the question and added a sample of the XML file @CristiFati

Comment: There are some fields you're searching for that re not present in the fragment. I'd still say to archive and upload one such file on a public server. Also, fix your code (*My\_Xpath\_NS* is undefined, there are others).

Answer (score 0):

If you write it as a streaming XSLT 3.0 transformation I would expect it to run in a minute or less, and to use a lot less memory. I'm not going to try and code it for you, because reverse engineering the requirements from your code is no fun, but 1min is a reasonable aspiration for the performance.